# Change vector memory allocation strategy?

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector, resize

Is there any way to change vector memory allocation strategy? using your own strategy instead of doubling vector size on resize.

([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11560904/vector-memory-allocation-strategy) a good explanation about memory allocation)

Answer (score 2):

No. There is no standard way to affect the growth strategy of `std::vector`.

At least, there is no guaranteed way to reduce the growth rate. You can use `reserve` before the growth triggering element addition which effectively allows you to control the lower bound of the growth rate.

> instead of doubling vector size on resize

That's not necessarily the strategy used by the vector implementation.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know， changing vector memory increasing strategy is not allowed in c++ unless you implement a vector yourself.

If you do want to control vector memory increasing strategy, you can use [reserve](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve).